# Extract 'B' records with lesser sequence number for each 'T' and greater than the sequence of the previous 'T' records for extracting each field

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hiveql, impala

Hi all I am trying to write a sql for retrieving records from landing table and load in to hive destination table. Please find landing table records below.

```
file_data,file_name
A0000000010000000100000001717,sample_1 
B0000000020000000100000015000,sample_1 
B0000000020000000100000015000,sample_1 
T0000000050000000100000000000,sample_1 
Z0000000060000000100000000000,sample_1 
A0000000010000000100000001717,sample_2
B0000000020000000100000015000,sample_2
T00000000300000001000000 0000,sample_2
B0000000040000000100000015000,sample_2
T00000000500000001000000 0000,sample_2
Z0000000060000000100000000000,sample_2
```

I have two columns in landing table such as file_data and file_name. Each rows 10 th position you can see sequence numbers like 1, 2,2,5,6 etc. 
I need to “Extract 'B' records with lesser sequence number for each 'T' and greater than the sequence of the previous 'T' records for extracting each field”
What will be the best way to go about this?.Please provide sample code. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what the intended output would be? (i.e. the downstream table?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and valuable time. Fortunately I could solve the issue.